# Does the sentence read correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is the sentence **The knife is a tool to cut** grammatically correct?

My logic is that the sentence phrased thus doesn't convey the intended meaning as it seems to convey the opposite idea, i.e., *The knife needs cutting*, which, of course, is meaningless. My logic stems from the fact that *to cut* here is a *gerundial infinitive* acting as an adjective and modifying the noun phrase *a tool*. Thus, I suppose, the sentence might better be rephrased, among many possibilities, as *The knife is a tool to cut [*vegetables with*.]*, or, *The knife is a tool that cuts.* [*no object needed*].

Is the original sentence correct or do I need to rephrase it to convey better the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to rephrase it. As you say, it's fine if you add a mention of what is being cut, but on its own it is better expressed as

> The knife is a tool for cutting.

Answer (score 0):

“The knife is a tool to cut” depends of how you view the sentence.

It could mean the knife is a tool which cuts an object.

It could also mean the knife is a tool which needs cutting.

It would be better to be more specific to reduce ambiguity.

Your logic is correct.

A better way to say it is “The knife is a tool which can cut”.

Or for example “The knife is a tool which can cut bread” if you want to be more specific.